# Get number days/weeks with .created_at as a date reference

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, time, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to compare `created_at` with differenct dates and get the number weeks.

I would like to do things such as

```
days = Time.now - Post.first.created_at
weeks = days/7
```

But comparing two `Time` objects gives me the result in seconds and I don't want to do the seconds/day conversion.

How would I get number of days/weeks when `created_at` is the date reference?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
days = (Date.current - Post.first.created_at.to_date).to_i
weeks = days/7
```

Answer (score 2):

I know you're looking for days/weeks but maybe this is something that would get you close to what you want.

Give the following a shot since you're using rails:

```
include ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper
distance_of_time_in_words(10.weeks.ago, DateTime.now)
=> "2 months"
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-distance_of_time_in_words